# Creating a specific exception for a function in PL/PgSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am trying to write a sql trigger that compares the old and new values. If the two values are different then I need to display an error saying that you can't update the names. That is the problem that I seem to be having, I don't understand how to display an error for an exception in PSQL The exact definition of my trigger is

```
write a trigger function named disallow_team_name_update that compares the OLD and NEW records 
team fields. If they are different raise an exception that states that changing the team name is 
not allowed.
```

The table that I am using for this problem is

```
  Table "table.group_standings"
    Column |         Type          | Modifiers
   --------+-----------------------+-----------
    team   | character varying(25) | not null
    wins   | smallint | not null   
    losses | smallint | not null
    draws  | smallint | not null
    points | smallint| not null
   Indexes:
     "group_standings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team)
  Check constraints:
   "group_standings_draws_check" CHECK (draws >= 0)
   "group_standings_losses_check" CHECK (losses >= 0)
   "group_standings_points_check" CHECK (points >= 0)
   "group_standings_wins_check" CHECK (wins >= 0)
```

The code I have right now, I need help for telling the user that they aren't aloud to change team names, but I am having issues doing so.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION disallow_team_name_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
            if(NEW.team <> OLD.team)
            /*tell the user to not change team names*/

    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_disallow_team_name_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF team ON group_standings 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE disallow_team_name_update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`RAISE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) to raise an exception. There are examples in the manual.

```
RAISE EXCEPTION ....
```

*(This looks like homework and you've asked about homework before, so I'm intentionally not giving a complete answer)*.